# What synchronization scheme should I choose to avoid deadlock on a realtime, C++/MFC application?

Tags: c++, mfc, concurrency, synchronization

I would like to ask you a question regarding which concurrency facility (CMutex, CSemaphore, CEvent) should I choose, to make a C++/MFC, application multi-threaded.

It is a real time, machine vision application, that is required now to execute concurrently and it needs refactoring, from it's previous single-threaded status.

A single iteration of my workflow is the following. I have 2 producers A,B (MFC Workers) that need to fill two separate data structures (1 each). A third thread, a consumer (MFC Worker as well) is blocked, until **both** data become available from A and B. Then, producers A and B must block (each, upon their data completion), C must wake up, perform a calculation, unblock A and B to continue and become blocked again, waiting for the next segments.

1. I must not use queues (Actor-like) - the blocking is a requirement
   :(
2. I tried CEvent and it works. AutoResetEvents for A,B to unblock a
   CMultiLock call on C and then a ManualResetEvent->Set() from C, to
   unblock A and B waiting on the latter event. My concern is when to
   reset this event (in case e.g. A miss the whole Set and then Reset.)
3. Do semaphores with plurality of 2 may stand for a better solution?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C must wait for two things to happen, so the most logical thing is that it waits for two auto-reset `CEvent` objects: one set by A and one by B.

When C is done, A and B must each then wait for a notification. Since there are two threads, and both must wake up, the natural thing is to use another pair of auto-reset `CEvent` objects, one for each of A and B. C can then set both when it is done.

A semaphore with a count of 2 would work for waking C --- C waits twice, and each of A and B notify --- but this means that C must wake up after the first notification in order to wait for the second, which is less than ideal.

Using a semaphore with a count of 2 for waking A and B afterwards has the potential for stolen wake-ups and confusion. C signals the semaphore twice. A wakes and takes a signal, does its processing and notifies C, and then waits on the semaphore again. Since B hasn't yet woken up, the semaphore is still available, so A takes it again. Meanwhile B is not stuck, since it won't get another signal, and C is stuck, since it will wait for the next value from B.

An alternative is to use the Windows Condition Variable API rather than events, but there doesn't seem to be an MFC wrapper for that. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682052%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Using the condition variable API would restrict the program to only running on Windows Vista (Server 2008) or later

Comment: I will proceed with that. I am not going to make premature optimization; I am just going to make it work at first with the second pair of CEvents. Then I will figure out, how much time does this switch, from user to kernel space, costs.

In relation to your alternative point. Do I really need to use an MFC wrapper for every sync object I use? I don't have much experience in MFC concurrent applications.

Comment: The other thing that concerns me is the cancellation of the C worker, how you escape safely the locking, without having alertable wait mode like in MsgWaitForMultipleObjects?

Comment: You don't need an MFC wrapper for everything, but if you are using MFC then often the wrappers are easier to use than the raw APIs. Personally, I prefer the C++11 wrappers.

Comment: To cancel thread C when it is waiting for the events you have several options. 1) use `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` or similar, in an alertable state, and use an APC to wake thread C. 2) Use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` and send C a message. 3) Wait for each event individually, but paired off with a third "cancel" event, so wait for A+cancel then B+cancel, using the "wait for any" option. If the cancel event is triggered then cancel.

Comment: I just experienced that MsgWaitForMultipleObjects with bWaitAll set to true, expects all handles **and** an event to be present in order to proceed.

Comment: Yes it does. I'd forgotten that, but the MSDN docs are clear on that issue. I guess that rules out that option.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was important.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a slight modification of your option 2 - use a CMultiLock on two events to block C; then use another *pair* of events to block A and B. C would set *two* auto-reset events to wake up each of A and B. Then you no longer have the race for the reset.

Comment: It is a candidate solution. As a matter of fact the most likely. Although, I liked the atomicity of signalling all (both of them) the enqueued threads via a single call.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a signalling system, using a counter protected by a mutex.  This keeps all the synchronization work confined to one small class that does notheing else.

```
A starts
A writes A-Data
A signals
A stops

B starts
B writes B-Data
B signals 
B stops

C starts
C reads A-Data and B-Data
C starts A, B
C stops


*Signal Class*

Mutex protected counter attribute

Receives signal for A, increment counter
Receives signal for B, increment counter
IF counter equals 2,  clear counter and start C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CEvent objects and than WaitForMultipleObjects() which allows you to wait on both objects via the third parameter 'bWaitAll'.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx